# Login Firebase/Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I created a widget to choose which page to render either `LoginScreen()`  or `HomeScreen()` called `Wrapper()`, here's the code:

```js
class _WrapperState extends State<Wrapper> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    var auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    auth.onAuthStateChanged.listen((user) {
      if (user != null) {
        print("user is logged in");
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(HomeScreen.routeName);
      } else {
        print("user is not logged in");
         Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(LoginScreen.routeName);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold();
  }
}
```

the error thrown when running `signOut()` function:

```
Error:  The method 'findAncestorStateOfType' was called on nullWrapper widget returned null
```

Comment: why are you using firebase authentication this way, instead you can sign in once, and on each app start you can decide where to route according to result of firebaseInstance.currentUser() method which gives you either the user or null

Comment: Can you tell me how to modify the code ?

Comment: or tell me how to do it pls

Comment: check this article first https://medium.com/flutterpub/flutter-how-to-do-user-login-with-firebase-a6af760b14d5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont have to do all of that, firebase authentication can handle login and keep the user logged in. Inside the first method of the lifecycle `initState`, you can do the following:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    var auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    auth.onAuthStateChanged.listen((user) {
      if (user != null) {
        print("user is logged in");
        //navigate to home page using Navigator Widget
      } else {
        print("user is not logged in");
         //navigate to sign in page using Navigator Widget
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Hi, i tried this and still have the same problem. It tells me it's logged out in debug console but doesn't navigate to the screen. And doesn't stay connected too.

Comment: I updated the question with the messages from debug console (using your suggested method).

Comment: now it doesn't even start the app just red page with error.I'll update the question

Comment: I updated the question now. I get te error when pressing run.

Comment: Don't add the code inside the build, instead add it inside the initState method in the State class

Comment: sorry i haven't learn this yet. Can you tell me more about it or tell me where to write what ? ty

Comment: Inside the _WrapperState class just copy the code and paste it

Comment: I did as you can see from the question update and have another error when logging out.

Comment: Okay instead of Navigator.of(),just use Navigator.push()

Comment: `Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignUp()),
        );`

Comment: `Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/second');` so just don't use of()